# What's the name of the song that plays during Morgiana's dancing scene at the end of ep 18 in Magi: The Labyrinth of Magic?

Tags: music, magi

If you don't know the name but know whether it's a Saudi-type song or some other type, let me know.

Comment: oops typo... i meant morgiana

Comment: FYI, you can [edit] your questions to correct typos and so forth. I have taken the liberty of doing so for you here.

Comment: the dance scene you are referring to is from episode 18.

Comment: yeah, you're right, ep18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it out... it's called "L'arabesque danse toujours"

Comment: you don't *"shut down the question"*, if you belive it's the correct answer to your question then you accept it so it can help other users who may have the same question

Comment: I'll have to wait two days then.

Comment: @mirroroftruth What on earth does it mean to add a "synopsis" of a piece of music? This answer is either correct or incorrect on its face (from what I remember of the Magi OST, it's probably correct), whether or not OP adds further detail.

Comment: Haha my mistake , it more like typing same thing again and again , you forget that you are typing something else

Comment: It's the most i had and the answer is correct, cause i found it out, (grammar nazi must of downrated the answer XD) i'm a composer that's why i also had a secondary thing, i'm not good with words.